# R: How to present negative regression slope when doing lm?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, least-squares, lm

When I used lm followed by plot in R, I get the following results. The problem is that the red line is theoretically wrong. The relationship is supposed to be inversely proportional, but (I suppose) because of the nature of OLS regression and the weightage of high value-data points, the line turned out positive.

Removing data is not an option.
This is a multiple regression. Point size (corresponding to initial wetness) is the second predictor.

Is there a way to pre-determine that the slope should be negative?
Appreciate any advice.

[image]

Comment: This plot is crying out "log-log".

Comment: Physical understanding should guide the model you are fitting. It won't be $y = b_0 + b_1 x_1 + b_2 x_2$.